# Google Analytics report showing the number of users that have completed each number of goals

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

In **Google Analytics** how do I report on number of users per number of goals?

I need to know how many users convert two, three or more different goals in a specific period. The site has 18 goals.

Comment: I'm not sure how you'd view data on # of goals per user for a specific period... you can view # of goals by creating a custom segment, but this only shows you goals per user per session. Starring this question as would like to see if someone else has the answer.

Comment: Thanks. A segment would do, but I need it to be more than per session. Anyway if you want to point a link to on how I can do it per session please do. I don't know that either. Thanks.

Comment: No problem! In the main reporting area you'll see a button near the top of the page that says '+ Add Segment' click this and choose '+ NEW SEGMENT' (sorry if I'm teaching you to suck eggs!). Now choose 'Advanced' and 'Conditions' on the left hand side. Click the dropdown (it defaults to 'Ad Content') and choose 'Goal Completions'. Here you can choose how many goal completions you'd like to show data on per session. Let me know if you get stuck - my instructions may be confusing!

Comment: It worked very well thank you very much @Daveth3Cat

Answer (score 2):

For this you can use Audience > User Explorer and then create segments (just like Daveth3Cat mentioned). With User Explorer you get the report for all sessions not just a single session.

[image: Screenshot of User Explorer]

It shouldn't be too much work - you'll see the % of users on the right as you change the desired number of goal completions.